# Uploading to Amazon S3 using signed S3 url in Grails

Tags: amazon-web-services, grails, amazon-s3

Curl successfully uploads the file to S3 using a signed url:

```
curl -v -k -X PUT \
  -H "x-amz-server-side-encryption: AES256" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/pdf" \
  -T "__tests__/resources/test.pdf" \
  "http://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/test.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=IDKEY&Expires=1489458783&Signature=SIGNATURE
```

I've tried replicating this in Grails using the REST client plugin:

```
  String url = "http://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/test.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=IDKEY&Expires=1489458783&Signature=SIGNATURE"
  RestResponse resp = rest.put(url){
      header "x-amz-server-side-encryption", "AES256"
      header "Content-Type", "application/pdf"
      body pdf
  }
```

But Amazon rejects the upload, saying the arguments are incorrect...probably due to the pdf being sent as a "body" parameter.  Any ideas?

Comment: *saying the arguments are incorrect*.  Don't paraphrase error messages.  What's the *exact* error, please?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a rest client to upload it would be simpler to use the AWS Java SDK in your Grails app.

See an example here of using a pre-signed url to upload http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObjectJavaSDK.html